# Cordura vs sensatez vs juicio vs sabiduría

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

Other than *juicio*, which has the additional meaning of a legal trial, these words all have to do with wisdom, judgment, and/or sense, as I understand it.

In what ways are they different?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cordura, sensatez and juicio can be (and are) used as synonyms according to RAE, but in everyday speaking (this is my view on the matter):

> **Cordura:** Sanity (opposed to madness)
>
> **Sensatez:** sense (opposed to imprudent)
>
> **Juicio:** Kind of old-fashioned, but used in sentences like "Has perdido el juicio?" (Have you lost your mind?)
>
> **Sabiduría** means Wisdom and can be used as a synonym of the other words
>   but usually is understood as a person with lot of **knowledge**, academic
>   or any other kind.

Comment: Very nice answer! Nothing to add! :-)

Comment: Sensatez = Sensibility

Comment: @MikMik sensibility = sensibilidad But I corrected anyway because I wrote the adverb and not the noun, so thanks! :D

Comment: Hmm, when I learnt that English *sensible* is not Spanish *sensible* but *sensato*, I thought that *sensibility* was its corresponding noun for "capacity for being sensible", and that idea's been there for years. You learn something new every day. Thanks